# How do I setup an Ember View class to be appended to a particular container?

Tags: ember.js

`Ember.View` has a nice method called `.appendTo("#container")` which would allow me to specify a container div for the view. However, when I use the router and `.connectOutlet method`, an instance of my view is created automatically based on convention and is added to the page *body* element by default. Is there a way to configure the class definition of the view so that upon creation it will be inside my desired `#container`. Here is my view:

```
Jimux.BuildsView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'builds',
  appendTo: '#jimux-header', #this was just a guess and did not work. but does some propery like this exist for the view?
  tagName: 'div',
  listVisible: true,
  ...
```

Another way to ask this question is: how do I tell Ember router to append a view to a particular item in the dom? By default the router appends the view to the *body*.

And here is the router bit:

```
# Connect builds controller to builds view
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet("builds","builds", Jimux.buildsController)
```

To clarify, I dont want to put my whole Ember app in a container. I have several views in my application, and most of them are fine directly in the body. But there are a couple like the one mentioned in this question, which I want to put inside `"#application-header"` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the root element for your application object.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#ember-app'
});
```

Edit:

Having re-read your question, I think you should look into named outlets, so you could do something like:

```
<div id="application-header">
    {{outlet builds}}
</div>

{{outlet}}
```

Comment: that is not my question here guys. I know that. But I dont want everything in my app to be inside the container, just this one view!

Comment: +1 for the solution. the only problem in my case is that the DIV I want to tap into already exist and is used on other parts of the web application. It is defined inside a template in the backend, so I would to do some refactoring. But, as you said this CAN be achieved using named outlet. Is there really no way to put a newly created view inside an existing dom element without putting that element in `application.handlebars`?

Comment: the connectOutlet() method returns the view, perhaps you can call .appendTo() on it ?

Comment: @sly7_7 that was a good idea, I just tried that but it does not work. It gave me this error exactly: `uncaught exception: You can't insert an element into the DOM that has already been inserted`

Comment: Hmm, this is not surprising, then I think your use case doesn't fit with outlets. When using router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet(...) ember puts the created view where the {{outlet}} is defined in the ApplicationView's template. I can't imagine a way of changing this.

Comment: is it not possible to create the view and then pass it to connectOutlet? I tried that but it didnt work, but maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Maybe you could use two ember applications? I'm not sure how feasible that is, but it might be worth exploring.

Answer (score 1):

well..after understanding your question, i remember having same trouble. Also, thing is i didn't find any way to do this even after going through the Ember code. But later i understood that its for good purpose only. I know you already might have come across with handlebars with which we can acheive this. If we give a view a ID to get appended, we are constraining the application and the whole use of ember becomes useless. Ok coming to you question, as far as i know, we can acheive that appending mustache templates in you div element of HTML.

```
<div id="jimux-header">
{{view Jimux.BuildsView}}
</div>
```

This way we can use the Jimux.BuildsView where ever you want and as many times possible. The Beauty of Ember you have to say...

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this solution does not consider router. As I said this is a view I am creating using `connectOutlet` method automatically.

Comment: oh I see what you are saying. Sure I can put new html elements in the handlebar template. But the element I am trying to insert the view into, already exist in the DOM. It is in fact the header and is already used in other parts of the application. What I want to do is put the view in an *existing DOM element* -- not wrap the view in a new DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `rootElement` in the application object.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#container'
});
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, please see my edit for clarification. I dont want the whole application to be inside a container, just a particular view.